# Differential Equations Text (Math GRE)?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, gre-exam

I am currently looking for a Differential Equations text from which to study for the Math GRE Subject Test. (As a side note, I currently own a copy of Stewart's Calculus.)

Any suggestions of textbooks (with solutions strongly preferred) are appreciated.

Comment: I took the math subject test in April, and I recall seeing 2 questions on ODE's. I would focus more on calculus and abstract algebra. But if you really want to, review linear first and second order (homogenous and non homogenous) ODE's, and any text should be fine for that.